# Get classes from assembly that implement a specific interface

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have an interface such as this:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T>
{
    void MyMethod(T obj);
}
```

I'm trying to find if an assembly has any classes that implement this. I found some examples but they are all demonstrate checking an implementation of a simple interface that don't have T.

Here is what I wrote:

```
var interfaceType = typeof(IMyInterface<>);
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);
var allTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
foreach(Type type in allTypes)
{
     var isImplementing = interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

I also tried doing this:

```
var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
var isImplementing = interfaces.Contains(interfaceType);
```

isImplementing is always false.

Comment: So what _does_ `interfaces` contain?

Comment: `interfaceType` is open generic type, you need to be checking the closed one isn't it? I mean you should check whether the class implements `IMyInterface<Something>`  or you're looking for open generic type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it with the second approach. However the interface types returned by `type.GetInterfaces()` will be of a specific type implementation e.g. `IMyInterface<String>`. So you'll have to check your interface type against the [GenericTypeDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Try this:

```
var interfaces = type.GetInterfaces();
var isImplementing = interfaces.Where(i => i.IsGenericType).Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == interfaceType);
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I have another question. If it isImplementing, how can I take the T type that's inside the IMyInterface<T> ?

Comment: @developer82, with the [GetGenericArguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on the interface type

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find if an assembly has any classes that implement this.

With your example you need a 'assemblyFile'.
Take a look at this example wich I used to get all the classes that implement IMyInterface using CurentDomain (System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain):

```
public IEnumerable<IMyInterface> GetClasses(AppDomain CurrentDomain)
    {
        var _type = typeof(IMyInterface);

        var _types = CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(_s => _s.GetTypes()).Where(i => _type.IsAssignableFrom(i) && !i.IsInterface);

        List<IMyInterface> _classes = new List<IMyInterface>();

        foreach (var _instance in _types)
        {
            _classes.Add((IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(_instance));
        }

        return _classes;
    }
```

***Also note the '!i.IsInterface' using this will not return assemblies which contains the interface**

I hope this will help you get some insight fixing your problem.